# What would happen in the Stern-Gerlach Experiment if silver had a different electronic configuration?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Silver has the electronic configuration of $\text{[Kr]}4d^{10}5s^{1},$ which was part of the reason why the experiment was successful and two spots could be observed when silver was used.

However, following "traditional" rules, silver should have an electronic configuration of $\text{[Kr]}5s^{2}4d^{9}.$ If this was actually the case, would there still be two spots on the detector screen? I'm not quite sure how having 9 electrons in the 4d subshell would change things.

Comment: I am no expert, but in the second configuration it is equivalent to having a hole in the d band with the same spin of an electron, so I think that it would not change the result